# jquery mobile auto complete - Null passed to action

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jsonp

Has anyone got auto complete to work?
the sample code of jquery (URL adapted)
My Action is called, however no value (null) is passed to the action??? Please HELP
(http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html)

```
<script>
        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
            $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
                var $ul = $( this ),
                    $input = $( data.input ),
                    value = $input.val(),
                    html = "";
                $ul.html( "" );
                if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
                    $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
                    $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"@Url.Action("ClientSearch","Schedule")",,
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {
                            q: $input.val()
                        }
                    })
                    .then( function ( response ) {
                        $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                            html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                        });
                        $ul.html( html );
                        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                        $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Html

```
<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" id="myPage">
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..." data-filter-theme="d"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your URL returns a value? Can you test your service separately?

Comment: The URL is called however as null is passed to it, it returns a null value, so the issue is that a null is orginally passed to the URL

Comment: Can you add console.log($input.val()) throughout to track the value that is passed in the data in your post. Is the value of your input really null? Do you possibly have the wrong selector?

Comment: Ok added that, like so, and can see the value at these points: if (value && value.length > 2) {
                     console.log($input.val());
                     $ul.html("<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>");
                     $ul.listview("refresh");
                     console.log($input.val());

Comment: Where else should I add console.log($input.val());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the issue! It should be: `data: { term: $input.val()}`